# Find the matching string and replace the next line

Tags: groovy

I am new to the Groovy. 
If the line contains the string then replace the next line in the file.

Found something in google, but I don't want to write a new file.

```
 newPomFile.withWriter { output ->
                  jars.eachLine{ line ->
                        if (!skipFlag)output.write(line)
                        skipFlag = false;
                        output.write("\n")
                        if (line.contains(calArtiName.toString().trim())){
                            output.write("            <version>"+calArtiVer+"</version>")
                            skipFlag = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You have to write a new file. Or load the entire file into memory, and overwrite the original file with a new file. Either way, it's a new file

Answer (score 0):

**You may looking for this :**

```
File a = new File ("fileName.txt"); 
boolean flag = false; 
a.text =  a.readLines().collect{ l -> 
    if(flag){ 
        flag=false;
        l += " hw r u"  //<=== Your code
    }
    flag = (l.contains('hi')) // <== Your condtion
    l
}.join("\n")
```